# ASP.NET -Search and access local disk or network files in web

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

How can i search and download local disk files from web?
some codes available for searching local disk files by C#. but not web based....

please help me friends for searching algorithm..

Thanks,

regards,
Raj.

Comment: What do you mean by "local disk files from web"?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you some asp.net web File Browsers, like ckfinder and a source code from codeproject.

http://ckfinder.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301328/ASP-NETUser-Control-File-Browser

From the moment you select your file, you can simple click on it to get it, or use a http handler to send it to the client.